# Kashyyyk and Endor levels

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Are these only available through the Salvage special events?

I just rescanned and Kashyyyk has disappeared from all scan fields, and Endor has appeared. Does that mean I can never get the Kashyyyk levels? I spent 250 bux trying, having only gotten one Worker (disappeared while in an elevator while switching apps), one crash on opening cargo, and a bunch of Imperial items I don't need.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can keep rescanning, and Kashyyyk should turn up eventually in one of the three slots.

But your experience of spending lots of bux to get junk is not atypical.

Comment: So how do you actually unlock any of these extra levels? , i've now just spent close to 600 bux sending out these probe droids with nothing but coins or imperial stuff i've already made so far.....

Comment: Speaking purely theoretically (my tower is fracked up, and won't give my bux) I think the best strategy is to keep rescanning until a planet is in the rare slot, then keep sending drones there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Kashyyyk, Endor and Chiss levels appear to only be available through using the Salvage droids.  Considering that they added a new level and there is not a seasonal icon in the corner (as there was for the holiday theme and service to the empire), I'm not sure this is a limited time special event.

You can keep rescanning as much as you want (or can pay for) which will change which locations are available to send salvage droids to.  One very useful tip: if a salvage droid is currently on a mission to a location when you rescan, that location will not change.  For example, say you have Kashyyyk in the middle (15 bux) slot, and  you send a salvage droid there and then hit rescan while it is on its mission - in this case, Kashyyyk will stay in the middle slot, and only the other two locations will reshuffle.  Another tip: One location can be in multiple slots at the same time; for example Endor can be in all 3 (free/5+ bux, 15 bux, 25 bux) slots at the same time.